# Similarity matrix in Affinity Propagation of Python

Tags: python

I want to run Affinity Propagation in python. I know that sklearn.cluster has this algorithm.it seems that sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation run it by computing the similarity matrix as negative euclidean distances. However, I have my own similarity matrix and do not want to use euclidean distances.
So I am wondering if there is any way that I put my similarity matrix as the input and run the algorithm based on that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that! See the following snippet

```
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

# compute the similarity matrix
af = AffinityPropagation(affinity='precomputed', verbose=True)
af.fit(similarity_matrix)
print af.labels_, af.cluster_centers_indices_
```